# "only to be brought low..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

consider below text:

> Throughout literature we find recurring tales of forthright people who are outspoken in condemning illegal practices **only** to **be brought low** themselves when they, or members of their family commit such acts.

As I search, I found that (given to [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39562/meaning-of-be-brought-low)) **to be brought low** means decline of someone's position, credit, or dignity.

I think, the writer tries to make the point of "These guys, when one of their family commit such acts, They only  bring low themselves   "

I have tow questions:

1. > Am I right about the author's intent ?
2. > I cannot understand that **only** in the middle of the sentence. For me, it is more sensible to write sentence having pattern of that "X only when Y ". I am confused about the structure used in the original text.

Comment: Other answerers explained well about "brought low" and "only".  I just want to point out that the sentence says the person is "brought low" whether they commit the act or a family member does. It doesn't say whether the family members might be "brought low" as well. So it doesn't mean, as you suggested, that _only he_ would be "brought low".

Comment: For the *only* part, **[...only to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/only-to-do-something)**: used for saying that what happens next is disappointing or unpleasant; *I tore open the box, only to discover that some of the parts were missing.*

Comment: @BrianHitchcock yes In my suggested sentence, the they refers to (these guys). Under this consideration, did I made a mistake in writing ? I mean, does the suggested sentence imply something different from what is my intent.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Is the comma necessary in such sentences ? I don't see the comma in original sentence while your and TRomaon's examples uses comma.

Comment: IMHO, the comma before *only to ...* is not mandatory, but it's probably reasonably used more often than not, to add the rhythm to the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

To be brought low by one's misdeeds is to go from a social position of high standing to one of utter disrepute. For example, a politician who campaigns on a moral-values platform and then is discovered partying in a hotel room with cocaine and prostitutes.

In the sentence, the only-clause introduces a *reversal* of fortune or a thwarted expectation.

**She took the hour-long bus ride to the airport, only to learn that her flight had been cancelled.**

**He drove his new car to the car-wash, where he had it washed and waxed, only to have it soiled ten minutes afterwards by a flock of starlings which had just been eating mulberries.**

**He was congratulating himself on the great time he was making on the drive north, only to be delayed at the border crossing.**

**They took a cab to the movie theater, only to find that the 10PM showing was sold out.**

Answer (score 1):

You indeed understood the sentence correctly.

The word *only* can have different meanings. It is often used as a restriction, but that is not the case here. In your sentence it has the meaning of a bad result as the consequence of an action. Here's a definition from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only):

> used when saying that something unpleasant will happen as a result of an action or a failure to act: