# What kind of grammar (structure) is used in this sentence? "only to be brought low themselves"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, phrase-structure

I saw the following sentence:

> Throughout literature we find recurring tales of forthright people who are outspoken in
> condemning illegal practices **only to be brought low themselves** when they, or members of
> their families, commit such acts.

I don't understand the grammar (structure) of the term in bold. Can anyone please explain and give more examples? The position of "themselves" is making me very confused.

Source: Barron's 1100 Words You Need to Know

Comment: We keep hearing about people who complain about the sins of *others* - ***but then it turns out that they themselves** are guilty of the committing those same sins*. This use of "only", as in *He was full of excitement when he arrived at the party - **only to be disappointed** when they wouldn't even let him come in through the door*, uses "only" as a ***negative contrasting conjunction*** (precisely equivalent to ***but** he was disappointed* in my example).

Comment: Please always [cite the source of quoted text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: Dear FumbleFingers, I've heard (read) sentences like what you said (only to be disappointed). But having "themselves", especially without "they"or "them" before it makes me very confused. I was even thinking maybe it is only some typo or error. According to my knowledge this sentence should have been either "only to be brought low" or (i'm not really sure) "only for them to be brough low". Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Related: ["only to be brought low..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/65119/41273)

Comment: Dearl @Laurel, my problem is not with the meaning of the sentence. My problem is with the position of "themselves" in the sentence. I think "themselves" should be omitted here. Do you have any other example of some usage of "themselves" (or myself, etc.) in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to be brought low** is an idiomatic expression in English.

It can mean to lose one's social position OR it can mean to become sad/depressed.

It means **they themselves** feel bad when family members commit acts they have been criticizing.

Themselves is used to emphasize the they.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer.
My question is why "themselves" is used in such a way?
Shouldn't it omit "themselves"? Or shouldn't it be "only for them themselves to be brought low"? Thank you

Comment: @HamedHomaee It just emphasizes the third person plural. It is not needed grammatically; it is an "intensifier". Did you do it? Yes, I did it. Compare: Yes, I did it myself.

Answer (score -1):

"themselves" refer to "forthright people who are outspoken in condemning illegal practices"

The implicit "high" refers to people who preach morality ("outspoken in condemning illegal practices"), possibly referring to how in old Western churches, preachers give sermon from an [pulpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulpit) raised high above the floor, even with a canopy to serve as a sounding board.  It is the preacher's job to rebuke the congregation who sit at the "low" places (the pews) to repent from their sins.

So "brought low" means when the preacher commits the very act that they are outspokenly condemn, everyone will see that the preacher's place should be "low" at the pews himself/herself.  The preacher should be embarrassed.

"low" is an adverb for "brought"